# Calling CHL function, outside of view

Tags: c, web

So I have a [CHL](https://github.com/it4e/CHL) function x

```
void x(char * args) {
    char * arg;    

    arg = chl_next_arg(args);
    printf("%s<br />", arg);
}

chl_func_append("printx", x);
```

Normally I would call this function from within a view, but I want to be able to call it from the code like it would be a normal function. Like:

```
x("hello"); // should output hello
```

But since it is not a normal function, but using chl formatting I'm not sure how to do it. Do you know of any way how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, so apparently there is a function called *chl_func* which enables you to envoke a chl function using its predefined name passed to *chl_func_append*, as well as passing it arguments.

```
chl_func("printx", "Output");
```

src: https://github.com/it4e/CHL/wiki/chl_func